# Expected averages of ordered draws from a uniform distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Suppose I take $n$ independent draws from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and call the set of those draws $N$. Then define $X \subset N$ as the $K$ largest draws, and $Y \subset N$ as the $N-K$ smallest draws. What is the probability that the mean of $X$ is $k$ times larger than the mean of $Y$?

Comment: Exactly $k$ times or at least $k$ times?

Comment: At least that large - sorry.

Answer (score -1):

So I think, I can combine the order statistic of the uniform distribution and the Bates distribution as follows.

First, the order statistic of the $K^{th}$ largest draw is distributed via a Beta distribution with parameters $K, n-K+1$. So I can define a random variable $a$ based on that.

Then, because each draw is independent, I can use that a to bound intervals and apply the Bates distribution as follows:

$$pr(\mu(X) > k \mu(Y) ) =  pr(Bates\left( [a,1], K\right) > k \; Bates\left( [0,a], n-K \right)) $$

This implies:

$$\int_{0}^{1}Beta(K, N-K+1)\int_{0}^{1}Bates\left( [0,a], n-K \right) \int_{xt}^{1} Bates\left( [a,1], K\right) dx dt da.$$

Does that look right?

Comment: How the distribution of mean of dependent ordered r.v.'s relates to the Bates ditribution?

Comment: They are not dependently ordered. The draws are independent. Of course, some will be larger than others and so they can be ordered once drawn.

Comment: Well, simply check your calculations for $N=2$, $K=1$, $k=2$. The probability that maximum of two uniform samples is at least twice larger than minimum $P(X_{(2)}>2X_{(1)})=\frac12$. Given $a$ fixed, The probability that uniformly $[a,1]$ distributed r.v. is at least twice grater than another independent uniformly $[0,a]$ distributed r.v. is $$P(U([a,1])> 2U([0,a]))=\begin{cases}\frac{4-5a}{4(1-a)}, & a\leq 1/2\\ \frac{1+a}{4a}, & a>1/2\end{cases}$$ and integrating this with pdf $2(1-a)$ of Beta(1,2)  gives $\frac12+\frac12\ln(2)$.